# How do I display breadcrumbs on "Products tagged with" pages in Magento?

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

I can't figure out how to get breadcrumbs to show up on the "Products tagged with" page in Magento. I get breadcrumbs everywhere else, including the search results page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following layout update to the app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/layout/tag.xml file under <tag_product_list>:

```
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
  <action method="addCrumb">
    <crumbName>Home</crumbName>
    <crumbInfo><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></crumbInfo>
  </action>
  <action method="addCrumb">
    <crumbName>Tags</crumbName>
    <crumbInfo><label>tagged products</label></crumbInfo>
  </action>
</reference>
```

I guess it would be more desirable to have the second crumb change depending on the tag displayed, but this would require some more complex modifications. Let me know if you are interested and I might be able to help you out.